# Add DOCTYPE to Masterpage with SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm attempting to add a DOCTYPE Declaration to a SharePoint masterpage so i can get some CSS code working. I'm new to sharepoint and I do not know where to look for the masterpage so it can be editted. I have access to SharePoint Designer and site settings.

Ive tried just adding the tag to the default.apsx page but i get an error stating that things cannot be added outside of a script.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 2010, in SharePoint Designer there is a Masterpages link on the left navigation once you connect to the site.  There is already a DOCTYPE tag in the masterpage, so if you need to modify it, be sure to modify the existing one instead of adding a second one.

Comment: where is this doctype decalaration? I searched the document for "DOCTYPE" and could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually under /_catalogs/masterpage.  Are you a site admin or site collection admin, otherwise you might not be able to edit the masterpage.